# Moving nested json to top level in logstash

Tags: logstash

My log has structure like -

```
  {
     a:  {
            b:   {
                   c: 12
                 }
         }
     z: 514
  }
```

I want to convert it to { z:514, b: {....}}

When I try to add_field it can add only stringified JSON. I have also tried rename and copy but none seems to work for me. What is the correct way to do it ?